# Reading File Error.. Microsoft Assembly

Tags: file, assembly, x86

I am workin on a pretty big program in Assembly

I have a bit of a problem in this specific piece of code

```
ToArray proc _FH:word ; _FH File Handler ;non-void function returns -1 if error 
LOCALS
push AX BX CX
MOV BX, _FH
MOV CX, 400
MOV DX, offset FileBuffer
MOV AH, 3FH
INT 21H
JC ErrorReading
call puts, offset Read_Success
JMP DONE
ErrorReading:
call puts, offset Read_Error
MOV DX,-1
DONE:
pop CX BX AX
ret
ToArray endp
```

I have { 1 2 5 6 } in the opened file but after callin INT 21H it just fills the array with 80241 80241..

Why is this happening :?

Comment: What are you viewing the buffer as? 80241 clearly doesn't fit in a byte, so are you viewing the data as words (or dwords)? And is that 80241 decimal or hex? What's the value of `AX` after executing the interrupt?

Comment: the buffer is a Word am reading Integers though.. 
from having 1 3 5 6 I have 8241 8243 8245 3382 10 
all in decimal values and AX equals to 9h :?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> from having 1 3 5 6 I have 8241 8243 8245...

That looks like correct data to me.
The decimal numbers `8241 8243 8245` when viewed as hexadecimal would be `0x2031 0x2033 0x2035`. `0x20` is the ascii code for the space character, `0x31` is the ascii code for `'1'`, and so on. So you're looking at the string `"1 3 5 "`. It's just that you picked a representation of the data that makes this hard to see.
Unless the file is using Unicode or some other multi-byte character encoding you're better off viewing the characters as bytes rather than words.

Comment: Aha I see.. Ok I just need to add those numbers how I can do this while I am getting the ASCII Code :?

Comment: Process the buffer byte by byte, check if a byte is in the range '0'..'9' - if it is, subtract '0' and use the result for whatever operation you need to perform.